# How to reconcile the fact that mathematical proofs are logical implications with the lack of a formal calculus equivalent to the logical implication?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic, symbolic-logic

Theorems follow from axioms. That is, theorems are the logical consequence of axioms. Thus, mathematical proofs  are essentially deductive. Proofs are all essentially logical implications. There is not one proof in mathematics which is not a logical implication.

Yet, mathematicians make nonsensical or contradictory claims on the subject.

First, mathematicians seem to all insist that theorems are proved using the material implication, not the logical implication, even though this is patently false since most theorems are not even proved formally, since mathematicians still today prove their theorems essentially in the same way as they did before mathematical logic and the introduction of the material implication.

Mathematicians keep using the label "material implication" even though the material implication is not an implication. It is essentially and obviously a simple logical operation.

Some mathematicians say, without proof, that the material implication is *equivalent* to the logical implication. How can prove using the logical implication that the material implication is equivalent to the logical implication and this even though you do not understand the logical implication?

Others mathematicians say, again without proof, that the material implication "improves" on the logical implication understood in the Aristotelian or "colloquial" sense. How can you claim to improve on something you do not understand?

Some mathematicians also claim that mathematics is a sort of meaningless formal "game", based on the mindless application of arbitrary rules of derivation. Yet, you cannot apply a rule without relying not only on the rule itself, but on your own logical capacity. Mindless is not an option. The application of a rule is itself a logical implication, something which is made explicit in the use of the expression "rule of inference". For example, the material implication itself can be used through the application of a rule of inference, a sort of bogus modus ponens called... "modus ponens", written in two different ways:

> **p ⊃ q
>
> p
>
> ———
>
> ∴ q**

Or:

> **p ⊃ q, p
>
> ————
>
> q**

So, how do you personally reconcile the fact that mathematical proofs are essentially deductive, and therefore necessarily involves logical implications, with the fact that there is still today in mathematics no formal calculus logically equivalent to the logical implication?

Comment: Kant suggested that our entire reason is based on a set of tautologies. There's no deepest rule that would be able to validate all other rules. Knowledge is a set of circular assumptions, kind of the dictionary is a set of definitions that depend on other definitions in the same dictionary, in a circular fashion.

Comment: Quite nonsensical...  When mathematicians prove a theorem from axioms they “show” that the theorem is a logical consequence of the axioms. This amount s to prove that: if the axioms hold, then the theorem holds, and this fact is not affected by “concerns” about material implication.

Comment: Remind: material ilmplication is **not** logical consequence, also if the two are connected. We can set up a logical calculus with e.g. only negation and disjunction as connective (so, no “weird” material implication at all) and the def of logical consequence will not change of an epsilon.

Comment: Your concern will disappear as soon as you forget of the “wrong” names: one is the *conditional* connective and the other is the relation of “logical consequence “. No “implication “ at all

Comment: "How do you personally reconcile" is off-topic on this site. But since mathematicians prove their theorems using "logical implication" they must be understanding what that is and what it is "equivalent" to.

Comment: @Conifold Sorry, you are being repeatedly incoherent. I shall try to ignore your comments.

Comment: Taking out "personal reconciliation" there is a good question underneath that has been discussed in recent literature, e.g. by Rav and Azzouni: given that mathematicians do use semi-formal reasoning in practice why do the theorems still match theorems in formal axiomatic systems like ZFC? And the answer is that the semi-formal reasoning of mathematicians modifies colloquial use of connectives in the direction of Boolean algebra. And not just implication, disjunction and negation as well, see e.g. [Azzouni](https://academic.oup.com/philmat/article-abstract/12/2/81/1412294).

Comment: The question would be much better if it wasn't made up from mere assertions about what 'mathematicians' say or do, but provide some quotes instead to show who really does say what you claim and in which context/why.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Apparently, you are still the same one who deleted my answer.

Comment: Apparently, you are still the same one unable to differ between personal disagreement on a given subject matter and constructive feedback. As if disagreement with you would disqualify the judgement of others, which is a dangerous, if not outright wrong stance to have

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Your comment is fallacious. I am perfectly happy to have people I could disagree with and that is not the point. The point is that you deleted my answer because you disagreed with the view I expressed in it.

Comment: That's not true. As I stated elsewhere, I deleted it because the view you expressed in it was not sourced *and/or irrelevant/tangential to the question*. This made it an answer to a different question, basically. Hence, it wasn't an appropriate answer to the question at hand, even if it contained (about 10% of the text) relevant content.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Your assertion is absurd. My answer was 100% relevant. The question was "*can an argument containing a contradiction be valid argument*". My answer contained three distinct parts: Part One giving an example of a valid argument containing a contradiction, namely A ∨ (B ∧ ¬B) ⊢ A; Part Two giving an example of an invalid argument containing a contradiction, namely A ∧ ¬A ⊢ B; and then Part Three to provide the necessary explanation that A ∧ ¬A ⊢ B is proved valid in mathematical logic and why that is. How is that not relevant?!

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking My view is sourced. The source.is me and it is perfectly clear that it is me. This is the point of providing answers. And it can only be me since nearly 100% of mathematicians accept that A ∧ ¬A ⊢ B is valid, if only because this is what they have learned at school.

Comment: This q is closed, but mathematically the reconciliation is fairly trivial in the sense of the [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem). Indeed one seldom needs to (explicitly) exhibit the material implication in many proofs, but it's not clear what is your point with that. Your final statement that "there is still today in mathematics no formal calculus logically equivalent to the logical implication" is simply false; see Hilbert-style calculus, Gentzen calculus etc. Mathematicians did formalize the latter notion too.

Comment: It's actually not incredibly interesting in much of mathematics, but in other areas where logic gets applied, e.g. computer science, it's quite common to define Gentzen-style systems that have no notion of "material implication" defined; this is quite common in [programming language] typing systems etc. Besides, in logics that map to residuated algebras, one has *two* (non-identical) notions of "material implication" (the left & right residuals); see Lambek calculus, which has applications in linguistics, as well as serving as basis for the study for [much of] substructural logics.

Answer (score 2):

There is some need for clarification here. Nobody claims that material implication is the same as logical implication. Material implication, or the material conditional, is an object-language propositional connective. It is the same kind of thing as ⋀ and ⋁ - its job is simply to take two truth values as arguments and return a truth value as a result. It can be defined syntactically using natural deduction rules, such as the classical rules of modus ponens and conditional proof. It can also be defined semantically using a truth table. The two definitions are provably equivalent.

Logical implication, or logical consequence, is a meta-level relationship between sentences; it holds when one sentence is logically entailed by others. Again, it can be divided into syntactic and semantic components. We use the turnstile Γ ⊢ α to indicate that α is the syntactic consequence of Γ, which can also be read as Γ proves α, or α is a theorem on Γ. We use the double turnstile Γ ⊨ α to indicate that α is the semantic consequence of Γ, which is usually cashed out using model theory as every model of Γ is a model of α. For first order predicate logic, syntactic and semantic consequence are provably coextensive.

Having distinguished material and logical implication, there is now an important relationship between them. For any argument, there is a corresponding conditional sentence. For example, if we have an argument A, B, C; therefore D, we can formulate a sentence "if A and B and C then D". Naively speaking, the argument is valid if and only if the corresponding conditional sentence is *necessarily* true. We can then give more concrete form to the naive 'necessarily' by representing it syntactically as 'provably', or semantically as 'under all interpretations'. Now here is the big pay-off... If we are using classical logic, the 'if/then' that appears in the corresponding conditional sentence is material implication. In other words, an argument such as A, B, C; therefore D is classically valid if and only if the sentence "(A ⋀ B ⋀ C) → D" is provable, where → is material implication.

This is fundamentally why material implication is useful in logic. It is not because all conditionals are material implications - they are not. It is because material implication is the object-language connective that corresponds to the classical relationship of entailment. Material implication is useful just because classical logic is useful.

As to what mathematicians do: they are in the business of providing proofs of theorems, which can be represented as Γ ⊢ α. There are many formal systems of calculus that characterize the logical implication relation ⊢. There are Hilbert-style axiom systems, natural deduction systems, Gentzen-style sequent calculus. Many of these include material implication because it is convenient and useful. For example, the axioms of modal logic are expressed using material implication. When mathematicians publish their work, they typically do not put in all the formal logical apparatus because it is a lot of extra work and they can usually be sure that their audience will be familiar with the logic.

Comment: First, thanks for a very good answer. Compared to those of other would-be experts, this one shows you understand the question, the language is precise and you address at least some of my points. And there is no insult implicit in it as is often the case in most answers as soon as people disagree with you.

Comment: Now on the substance. How do mathematicians prove that, in your own words, *the 'if/then' that appears in the corresponding conditional sentence is material implication*?

Comment: Further, limiting ourselves to what mathematicians call "Classical Logic", how saying that *the 'if/then' that appears in the corresponding conditional sentence is material implication* isn't the same thing as saying that a material implication is logically equivalent to a logical implication?

Comment: I didn't claim that "*all conditionals are material implications*".My claim is that mathematicians all believe that a material implication is a logical implication, or logically equivalent to a logical implication, and therefore to the corresponding conditional.

Comment: "*When mathematicians publish their work, they typically do not put in all the formal logical apparatus*" So, most of them do the formal proof and yet abstain from publishing it?! I don't have any reason to believe that. If this is what they did, the formal proof would be available somewhere for those interested.

Comment: "*For example, the axioms of modal logic are expressed using material implication*" I'm not interested about mathematical logic examples. The question is whether mathematicians outside mathematical logic explicitly use the material implication or not. Can you give routine examples in algebraic topology or affine differential geometry?

Comment: I call "logical implication", any expression φ → ψ, where φ and ψ are logical expressions, and which is logically equivalent to the conditional If φ is true, then ψ is true. This is how it has always been understood and is still today usually understood, including by most mathematicians, most of them being in fact unaware that a material implication is not at all the same thing, or even the same kind of thing, as a logical implication. Your definition is typical of mathematical logic and this is only relevant to a small minority of mathematicians.

Comment: The if/then that appears in the corresponding conditional sentence is material implication if and only if the logic is classical. This is another way of saying that material implication is the propositional connective that corresponds to the classical relationship of entailment. It is a consequence of the deduction theorem.

Comment: Most of your other points are simply confusing material implication with logical implication. I was careful to distinguish them.

Comment: When a mathematician produces a proof of a theorem, the proof is always selective about what steps are made explicit. It is part of the craft of becoming a good mathematician to learn which parts of a proof are tricky and need to be rendered in detail and which parts are straightforward and do not. Since mathematical publications are mostly read by other mathematicians there is no need to provide all the elementary steps. If you need the elementary steps you can still get them by using a computer theorem proving assistant.

Comment: I have a textbook of set theory on my bookshelf that uses material implication on almost every page. I am not sure how you would explain set theory without it. Other branches of mathematics typically use set theory as their foundation. I found an online textbook of algebraic topology that in the first section defines all of its terms using set theory, and I suspect this is typical. So indirectly, all branches of mathematics are relying on material implication (provided they are classical).

Comment: So you cannot exhibit evidence that mathematicians use the material implication outside mathematical logic. I hope you understand that using set theory as foundation does not in itself demonstrate that the proofs done in set theory are valid, even assuming that the theorems are correct. And the fact that you don't know how you could prove set theory without the material implication is irrelevant. My point is whether mathematicians use the material implication outside mathematical logic. You comments confirm they do not.

Comment: Mathematicians use material implication to prove the theorems of set theory and they use the theorems of set theory to prove the theorems of other branches of mathematics. If you think that the theorems of set theory are invalid that would be very weird. Mathematicians use set theory for a good reason. And yes, you can reduce mathematical proofs all the way down to logical proofs, its just that it is a lot of work for little or no benefit. But a computer theorem proving assistant will do it for you.

Comment: I don't doubt that most theorems of set theory are correct, but that does not mean that the proofs themselves are valid or that the material implication is logically equivalent to the logical implication..

Answer (score 0):

*Long comment*

You can take a look at a simple piece of "real mathematics" and consider how much "formal logic" is implicit in that three lines theorem.

A lot of "classical" propositional logic is implicit  in it, without strictly formal propositional calculus at all.

See [David Hilbert's *The Foundations of Geometry* (1899)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms), English translation, [Th.1, page 3](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ewodzicki/160/Hilbert.pdf):

> **Theorem 1**. Two straight lines of a plane have either one point or no point in
> common [...]

The theorem asserts that two distinct straight lines can have *at most* one point in common, and can be stated more at length with: let **l** and **m** two distinct straight lines; if they have one point **P** in common, then **P** is unique.

The proof is by contradiction, using

> **Ax.I,1**: Two distinct points **A** and **B** always completely determine a straight line **a**. We write **AB = a**.

Answer (score -1):

*(This could be better suited as a comment, but my reputation score is too low to add comments)*

It might help if you make clearer what you mean by "logical implication": do you refer to another formalization of some rules of logic, or to the inner activity of the mathematician?

Although when you say

> most theorems are not even proved formally, since mathematicians still today prove their theorems essentially in the same way as they did before mathematical logic and the introduction of the material implication

one can convene with you, it is true on the other side that most working mathematicians nowadays believe that proofs *can* be formalized in a calculus, typically one involving material implication.

If your intent is criticizing the stance by which one says "Mathematics is a game of formal objects within the formal rules of logic", then you might be interested in Intuitionism (see e.g. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism)

Comment: There is one logical implication and it is not the material implication. It is the implication all logicians discussed during 2,500 years. So, no, I don't need to clarify. What mathematicians believe is also moot. The point is that their proofs are not articulated in terms of the material implication. It simply never figures explicitly. Ergo, the only implication they can possibly be using is the logical implication, as per their own intuitive logical sense. And intuitionistic logic is even worse. The whole of mathematical logic is not classical and therefore not logic at all.

Comment: Note that I didn't refer you to intuitionistic logic but to intuitionism

Comment: The link you provide does not make any difference. Did you even read it?!